# Upload ASP.NET C# project online

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have APS.NET project with C# in VS 2019.  I want to make my web accessible online. So I am trying to upload neccessary files to FTP via FileZilla.

For that in VS 2019 I clicked on project -> Publish -> Publish to folder.
[image: Public VS 2019]

It generated files that I need for my website to work so it made 2 files and 1 folder:
[image]

I uploaded these files to FileZilla but when I open url which should work I get such error:
[image: Forbidden]

When I right click on tictactoe.aspx file -> File permissions it seems that access is granted:
[image: settings]

What am I doing wrong?
My goal is to create tic tac toe game and put it online. I thought it would be a great option to create it in C# ASP.NET.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Xampp cannot run ASP.NET applications, unless you are using .NET core and you would need to configure Apache as a reverse proxy to run it. You can try to install IIS Webserver in your PC and see online how to set up your Website. You can even publish directly to IIS from Visual Studio, in the same way you did but selecting IIS instead of publish to folder.

Comment: Try to look at asp.net core and docker(if you building a project from scratch) - I believe these two are a great match.

Comment: One more question: @lsma you say xampp cannot run ASP. NET. Thats okey, thanks. Also I tried to upload genersted files to ftp server. But when trying to open the link I get message that I have no access to the content. How could I fix it?

Comment: You'd need to be more specific about what link, and how you uploaded, and what exactly you uploaded to, what exactly the error is. It's so vague we can't possibly guess what is really happening there.

Comment: @ADyson I added detals. Can you check it out please? :)

Comment: Ok that looks like you haven't set the file permissions correctly so that the webserver can read them

Comment: @ADyson I added one more photo to my question :)

Comment: On the remote server. If the only access you have is via FTP then you'd have to set them through that. Or is there any kind of control panel provided by the hosting company? I assume you bought some sort of asp.net hosting package?

Comment: It just a standart Apache server from Internet Service Provider.

Comment: Apache doesn't run asp.net (or at least not unless you used asp.net core and configured it as a reverse proxy with the .net built in webserver behind it, but it doesn't look like you did that, and most commercial Linux hosts wouldn't support it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226122/discussion-between-adyson-and-vytaute).